# Handler did not return a response message in xunit

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I am using **Moq** package for  writing unit test for my service.
I am mocking `HttpMessageHandler` for mock `HttpClient`
but I got this runt time error message

> System.InvalidOperationException : Handler did not return a response
> message.

here is my service methods

```
 public async Task<PaymentDataResponse> PaymentRequest(double amount, string mobileNo)
 {
     var client = GetClient(mobileNo);

     var request = new PaymentRequest()
     {
         Amount = amount,
         CellNumber = SuitablePhoneNumber(mobileNo),
         TerminalId = _paymentInfoSetting.TerminalId,
         RedirectUrl = _paymentInfoSetting.RedirectUrl
     };

     var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(_paymentInfoSetting.TokenPath, request, new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase });

     if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         throw new PaymentException();
     }

     var responseModel = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<PaymentResponse>();
     return responseModel.Data;
  }
  private HttpClient GetClient(string phoneNumber)
  {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_paymentInfoSetting.BaseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apiKey", _paymentInfoSetting.ApiKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("mobile", phoneNumber);
        return client;
   }
```

and this is my unit test :

```
     [Fact]
     public async Task PaymentRequest_ShouldReturnCorrectData() 
     {
       // Arrange
            
       var amount = _fixture.Create<double>();
       var mobileNo = _paymentInfoSetting.PhoneNumber;
       var paymentRequest = _fixture.Build<PaymentRequest>()
                                             .With(q => q.Amount, amount).With(q => q.TerminalId, _paymentInfoSetting.TerminalId).With(q => q.RedirectUrl, _paymentInfoSetting.RedirectUrl)
                                             .With(q => q.CellNumber, mobileNo)
                                             .Create();
            
       var paymentDataResponse = _fixture.Create<PaymentDataResponse>();
       var paymentResponse = _fixture.Build<PaymentResponse>().With(q => q.Data, paymentDataResponse).Create();
       var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      // response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paymentResponse), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        response.Content = JsonContent.Create(paymentRequest, options: new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase });

       var handler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
        
       // config 1
       //handler.Protected()
                //  .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                //    .ReturnsAsync(response);
    
       // config 2
//handler.Protected()
//    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req =>
//        req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result == JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paymentRequest)), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
//    .ReturnsAsync(response);
        
        // config 3          
 handler.Protected()
     .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req =>
         req.Content == JsonContent.Create(paymentRequest, null, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase })
         ), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
     .ReturnsAsync(response);
            
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler.Object);
            
        _httpClientFactoryMock.Setup(q => q.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(httpClient);
            
            
        // Act
        var result = await _service.PaymentRequest(amount, mobileNo);
            
        var resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        var paymentDataResponseJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paymentDataResponse);
            
            
        // Assert
        _httpClientFactoryMock.Verify(q => q.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
            
        resultJson.ShouldBe(paymentDataResponseJson);
            
     }
```

**config 1** is working, but I want to set specific request so I am trying **config 2,3** but I get the error.

Comment: In case the condition in the setup doesn't match the parameter, the `SendAsync` will return null. At this point I think that the problem is the format of the json string generated. 
Try to invert the check logic, instead of checking the string equality, deserialize the `req.Content` to a `PaymentRequest` instance and compare with the `paymentRequest ` variable. If you define `PaymentRequest` as a `record` the comparison is simple, if it is a `class` you must provide the comparison logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it with mocking `HttpRequestMessage`

```
var httpRequestMessage = _fixture.Build<HttpRequestMessage>().With(q => q.Content, JsonContent.Create(paymentRequest, It.IsAny<MediaTypeHeaderValue>(), It.IsAny<JsonSerializerOptions>())).Create();

var handler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
handler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req =>
          req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result == httpRequestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(httpResponseMessage);
```